# Restful API: Best practice for admin and user scope

Tags: laravel, api, rest, restful-url

I am building an API where users and admins can interact with the same data, but with different needs.
A user can also have access to the admin panel, if he has the "admin" role.

Let's see for example we have a resource like **Badges**. A Badge is simply a reward when you achieve some actions into the app.

```
GET http://localhost/api/v1/badges
```

An authenticated user can call this endpoint and it returns the list of all badges, if they have it or not, with progress details.

```
GET http://localhost/api/v1/badges?user_id=2
```

with `user_id` parameter, we can see these details of another user (if he allows it).

**But from the admin scope**, I just need to see the list of all badges, without achievement details (CRUD operations).

So I have 2 options in mind:

- Create "admin" endpoints: `GET http://localhost/api/v1/admin/badges`.
- Adding custom header "X-App-Scope" to identify if I am in admin or user.

I don't like the second one because I think I will have so many `if` statements and behavior in the same endpoint, depending of the scope.

Because I have lots of use cases like this, I want to make sure my API architecture is good to handle user/admin needs.

Do you guys have any idea/example to manage stuff like this?

Thanks!

Comment: if you have X-App-Scope why have the same information in the url?

Comment: This is 2 different ideas: "admin" in url means a second endpoint to list badges while X-App-Scope can be used in the same endpoint (/v1/badges) to distinguish if I want the simple list of badges or the list with the user achievement details

Comment: Is this a public API? Users most likely need to be auth'd to access the endpoints, check if the auth'd user is an admin, deliver different results

Comment: I can't do that because a user can be also an admin, and use this endpoint in both cases.

Comment: Use `http://localhost/api/v1/badges/simple` for a version without achievements?

Comment: I could do that indeed. What about the idea of adding a parameter `stats` to have the achievement details? like `http://localhost/api/v1/badges?with_stats`. Naming should be better I assume it ^^

Comment: If I ware you I would go for 2 different endpoints:
1) You expect different data on the output
2) It is easier to define, monitor, filter, ...  access/usage which is defined on per path basis

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference is to separate admin API routes from user ones. i.e. having two routes

/api/v1/badges

/api/admin/v1/badges

1. You will have two unique documentation, one for each route, which makes it easier to maintain and understand
2. It will be easier to tell the difference between the user and the admin versions
3. There is no need extra code to check for request headers or url params.
4. It makes your middleware less complicated, especially if authentication and permissions are handled there.
5. It is more scalable for teams as there is only one kind of request and response format per API.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed what I did in the end, but in reverse: `/api/v1/badges` to manage the resource and `/api/v1/users/badges` to manage the resource as a user.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is designed in the expectation that you would use two different [resources](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) here.

The core problem is this: how would a *general purpose* component, like a browser, know that your special resource needs to have this custom header added?

In particular, consider the case where I send to you a copy of the URL for this resource, and nothing else.  How are you to know to add the customer header to the request?

On the other hand, if you use different resources to share this information with each audience, everything *just works*.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to stay as simple/clear as possible is to make multiple endpoints, for each use case:

`GET http://localhost/api/v1/badges` to get all badges in raw data

`GET http://localhost/api/v1/users/badges` to get all badges with user stats (progression, achievement...) in a transformed format

`GET http://localhost/api/v1/users/{uuid}/badges` to get all badges with user stats (progression, achievement...) in a transformed format for the specified user, if his profile is public

Now I have a lot of `/users/XYZ` endpoints, but my code seems easier to read & maintain, and I don't really need to see the code to guess what data will be returned, the conditions, etc...

I keep wondering how the other APIs are written when you have an admin section, because having `/users` everywhere isn't really "pretty", and I don't see that anywhere else.